# Web.config can't see my assembly

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, web-config

I'm getting errors when I try to reference one of my assemblies in my ASP.NET web application's web.config. I'm trying to set up a <profile> provider, but when I removed the <profile> node, the next place it was referenced threw the same error.

The error I'm getting is:
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MyNamespace' does not exist in the namespace 'MyAssembly' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The assembly isn't a gac assembly. It just lives in the projects bin directory.

Does anyone have any common reasons that the assembly can't be found? 
It's been copied into the project's bin directory. I checked that it's the right assembly in the right place. 
The type name is definitely right. I copied it from another project and used reflector to verify that the type was actually in the assembly where I expected it to be.

Comment: Does the assembly have a strong name? Does the assembly have any dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid developer error (I knew it would be). The page I was looking at was in a sub-application in IIS that didn't have the assembly in it's own bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Set the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\ForceLog registry value to 1 (the value is a DWORD) to get more information. This will display a more detailed error page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx